# A question on (odd) perfect numbers

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, perfect-numbers

I have asked this question in [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1226126) a few weeks back, but did not receive any responses.  I have cross-posted it to MO, hoping that it *is* appropriate for this site.

Let $\sigma(x)$ be the (classical) sum of the divisors of $x$.

A number $N \in \mathbb{N}$ is called *perfect* if $\sigma(N)=2N$.

An *even* perfect number $U$ is said to be given in *Euclidean* form if $U=(2^p - 1){2^{p-1}}$ (where $2^p - 1$ is called the *Mersenne* prime).  On the other hand, an *odd* perfect number $L$ is said to be given in *Eulerian* form if $L = {q^k}{n^2}$ (where $q$ is called the *Euler* prime).

Notice that for even perfect numbers, trivially we have $1 < 2^p - 1$ (where $1$ is the exponent of the Mersenne prime $2^p - 1$).

Does a similar statement hold for odd perfect numbers?  That is, does $k < q$ always hold?

Comment: Note that the statement is true when $n < q$, as then we have $1 = k < n < q$.

Comment: You left out the essential condition that $k$ is odd.

Comment: Since squares are not perfect, I think that it is *implicit* that $k$ must be odd.  (In fact, it is known that $k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ holds.)

Comment: Trivially, $k < q$ always holds when $k = 1$.

Comment: However, [Brown](http://arxiv.org/abs/1602.01591) has recently announced a proof for the inequality $q < n$.